# error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, typescript2.0, angular2-universal

I am using [angular/universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) as starter which uses TypeScript 2 and Webpack 2.

I added packages `bluebird` and `nodemailer`. After adding these packages and related typings:

```
"@types/bluebird": "3.0.31",
"@types/nodemailer": "1.3.30",
```

it gives me this error in the terminal:

> ERROR in
>   /project/node_modules/@types/nodemailer/node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts
>   (772,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.
>
> ERROR in /project/node_modules/@types/bluebird/index.d.ts (772,1):
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.

**[Not sure whether it helps]** Note after installing **@types/nodemailer**, @type/nodemailer has its own node_modules folder including @type/bluebird (which is an old bluebird typings version 2.0.0):

[image]

My **tsconfig.json** file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"]
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "!node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

How can I solve this error? Thanks

Comment: I ran across this same error message recently but with jquery, and adding typeRoots in tsconfig.json resolved it. More info in [Minko Gechev's blog](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what cause it. But after updating all of them to new version packages:

```
"bluebird": "3.4.1",
"nodemailer": "2.5.0",
"@types/bluebird": "3.0.32",
"@types/nodemailer": "1.3.31",
```

And I didn't change any other codes. The issue is gone.